# python: fast dict lookup from disk

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a big dictionary (1mil keys) in the form of:

```
{
    key1: {
        file1: [number_list1],
        file7: [number_list2],
        file10: [number_list3],
        ...
    }
    key2: {
        file1: [number_list4],
        file5: [number_list5],
        file2: [number_list6],
        ...               
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Due to various constraints, after building it I can't keep it in memory and have to dump it on disk in its pickled form. However, I still want fast lookup from disk to any one of the keys.

My idea was to divide the big dict into smaller chunks (ballpark of 0.5-1MB). This requires an additional key:chunk mapping but allows me to load only the necessary chunk during lookup. I came up with the following algorithm:

```
  def split_to_pages(self, big_dict):
    page_buffer = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
    page_size = 0
    page_number = 0
    symbol2page = {}
    for symbol, files in big_dict.items():
        page_buffer[symbol] = files
        symbol2page[symbol] = page_number
        page_size += deep_sizeof_bytes(files)
        if page_size > max_page_size:
            save_page_to_file(page_number, page_buffer)
            page_buffer.clear()
            page_size = 0
            page_number += 1
    if page_size > 0:
        save_page_to_file(page_number, page_buffer)
```

This solution performs well for a static dict. However, since it represents a dynamic entity, it's very likely that a new key is introduced to or removed from the dict during operation. To reflect this change, my solution requires partitioning the entire dict from scratch. Is there a better way to handle this scenario? I have a feeling that this is a common problem which I'm not aware of and better solutions have already been proposed for this matter.

EDIT:

I tried `shelve`, about 0.5s key lookup time for a small database (2k keys), which is very slow. My half-baked paging algorithm described above was about 0.01s.
`sqlite3` did 0.4s lookuptime for a 1mil key table, I doubt mongo will be faster. There's just too much overhead for my use case. I guess I'll go on with my own implementation of a partitioned database.

Comment: I'm guessing this is the reason databases were invented?

Comment: Agreed.  You might try using `redis`, `mongoDB`, or some other NoSQL store.

Comment: You could give `tinydb` a shot. No idea how much data it can handle.

Comment: I was aware of databases, thought I wouldn't have to go that route as it's a bit of overkill to my application. I guess there's no alternative.

Comment: Before using databases, try the `shelve` module

Comment: I don't know anything (good or bad) about `shelve`, so maybe consider it.  Re: databases being overkill, though.  Setting up a pretty vanilla instance of mongoDB shouldn't be too much for the problem you're describing.  You wouldn't have to worry about optimization or high availability.  And it would be handy to have later if you have other data store needs.

Comment: _**want fast lookup from disk**_ - this is contradict without using a Database.  One possible approach is to Index your File with the Offset and Size of every Key/Record.

Comment: I tried `shelve`, about 0.5s key lookup time for a small database (2k keys), very slow. My half-baked paging algorithm described above was about 0.01s.

Comment: `sqlite3` did 0.4s lookuptime for a 1mil key table, I doubt mongo will be faster. There's just too much overhead for my use case. I guess I'll go on with my own implementation of a partitioned database.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using 32bit python?  If so, would moving to 64bit "solve" your immediate memory issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try on-disk key-value pair solution for python. Check out my project RocksDict which is an efficient solution for your problem: https://github.com/Congyuwang/RocksDict. It is much faster than dbm, and therefore much faster than shelve since it is based on dbm. If you wish to try RocksDict, use `pip install rocksdict`

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.